# Python PBI.PyBusyInfo stays on top

Tags: python, dialog, wxpython

I have the code below which opens Quicktime via applescript and does stuff to files, which take a little while and mustn't be disturbed. I want a dialog window to open on top of everything else, not matter what it must stay on top, which just says "Processing files, please wait". This code works, but as soon as quicktime opens via applescript the PBI.PyBusyInfo disappears. Any idea how I could do this please?

```
import wx
import os
import os.path
import wx.lib.agw.pybusyinfo as PBI
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

class ScrolledWindow(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, id, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, title, size=(510, 370), style=wx.STAY_ON_TOP | wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE & ~ (wx.RESIZE_BORDER | 
                                                wx.RESIZE_BOX | 
                                                wx.MAXIMIZE_BOX))

        self.tabbed = wx.Notebook(self, -1, style=(wx.NB_TOP))
        run_params = {}
        run_params["dropList1"] = ['HD 1920x1080', 'PAL 4x3', 'PAL 16x9', 'NTSC 4x3', 'NTSC 16x9']
        run_params["dropList2"] = ['Progressive', 'Interlaced']

        self.CreateStatusBar()
        menuBar = wx.MenuBar()
        menu = wx.Menu()
        self.SetMenuBar(menuBar)
        panel = wx.Panel(self, -1)
        self.Centre()
        self.Show()
        self.filePrep = PrepFile(self.tabbed, run_params)
        self.tabbed.AddPage(self.filePrep, "File Prep")

class PrepFile(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent, run_params):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)

        self.run_params = run_params
        self.fieldChoice = 'Progressive'
        self.formatOption = 'HD 1920x1080'

        outputOption = '''Format'''
        wx.StaticText(self, -1, outputOption, (33, 22), style=wx.ALIGN_CENTRE)

        self.choice1 = wx.Choice(self, pos=(35, 40), choices=self.run_params["dropList1"])
        self.choice1.SetSelection(0)
        self.choice1.SetFocus()
        self.choice1.Bind(wx.EVT_CHOICE, self.selectOption)

        fieldSetText = '''Fields'''
        wx.StaticText(self, -1, fieldSetText, (33, 82), style=wx.ALIGN_CENTRE)

        self.choice2 = wx.Choice(self, pos=(35, 100), choices=self.run_params["dropList2"])
        self.choice2.SetSelection(0)
        self.choice2.SetFocus()
        self.choice2.Bind(wx.EVT_CHOICE, self.fieldSet)

        self.buttonClose = wx.Button(self, -1, "Quit", pos=(195, 250))
        self.buttonClose.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnClose)

        greyBox = wx.StaticBox(self, -1, '', pos=(20, 15), size=(235, 130))

        outputtxt3 = '''Drag and Drop Quicktimes'''
        wx.StaticText(self, -1, outputtxt3, pos=(35, 170), style=wx.ALIGN_CENTRE)

        self.drop_target = MyFileDropTarget(self)
        self.SetDropTarget(self.drop_target)
        self.tc_files = wx.TextCtrl(self, wx.ID_ANY, pos=(38, 190), size=(200, 25))
        self.buttonSubmit = wx.Button(self, -1, "Submit", pos=(250,190))
        self.buttonSubmit.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.submit)

    def EvtRadioBox(self, event):
        self.mode = (event.GetString())

    def selectOption(self, e):
        self.formatOption = self.choice1.GetStringSelection()

    def fieldSet(self, e):
        self.fieldChoice = self.choice2.GetStringSelection()

    def setSubmissionDrop(self, dropFiles):
        """Called by the FileDropTarget when files are dropped"""
        self.tc_files.SetValue(','.join(dropFiles))
        self.selectedFiles = dropFiles
        print self.selectedFiles

    def submit(self, event):
        event.Skip()
        message = "Please wait..."
        busy = PBI.PyBusyInfo(message, parent=self, title="Processing Files") 
        wx.Yield()
        for item in self.selectedFiles:
            if os.path.isdir(item):
                print "It is a folder!"
                for root, dirs, files in os.walk(item):
                    for file1 in files:
                        if file1.endswith(".mov"):
                            currentFile = os.path.join(root, file1)
                            self.jesFile(currentFile)
        print "Finished"
        del busy

    def doSomething(self):
        print "Open Quicktime and process files via applescript"

    def OnClose(self, e):
        CloseApp()

class MyFileDropTarget(wx.FileDropTarget):
    """"""
    def __init__(self, window):
        wx.FileDropTarget.__init__(self)
        self.window = window

    def OnDropFiles(self, x, y, filenames):
        self.window.setSubmissionDrop(filenames)

app = wx.App()
ScrolledWindow(None, -1, 'App')
app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question seems to be missing the call where you start the AppleScript (it looks like you forgot to add the jesFile method to your example code). I can only speculate so much on your code that isn't in the posted example... but my guess is your call to do processing isn't a blocking call, so you either need to make it a blocking call, or save busy to a class variable that you delete when the non-blocking process call returns (hopefully you can bind a callback function for when that happens).